# Model View Controller: Does the Controller or Model fetch data off the server?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller

For example: Let's say I'm grabbing a list of names and saving it to an NSMutableArray. Do I implement the method of actually calling the server to fetch the data in the controller (UIViewController) or the model(Friends object)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a design decision that depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If your model only makes sense in the context of a single service, or if you want your model to provide access to all the data on the server, then build the connection to the server into your data model. This might make sense if you are, for example, building a client for a service like Twitter or Flickr.

On the other hand, if you're just grabbing a file from a server and that's the end of it, it may make sense to do the communication in the controller. Controllers tend to be less reusable and more customized for the particular behavior of the application. Keeping the specifics about where the data comes from out of the model makes the model more reusable. It also makes it easy to test -- you can write test code that just reads a local file and stores the data in the model.

Comment: This is what I was getting at, +1

Comment: This should not be the only reason for making the decision, but doing client-server communication in the controller also has the advantage that you may not need to implement a [notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html) mechanism from the model to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question. I think the best way is through a controller because it decouples your model from requiring the other model to be present for it to work properly.  Although I don't think you violate "proper mvc" by doing it in the model either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put it in the model. What you'll do is interrogate the model for the data and then the model will handle how to populate itself whether it's from an internal data store or an external one (like a server).

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the repository pattern. To do this, you create Repository objects in your Model folder and you place all of you database-related methods in them. Your controllers call the repository classes to get the data. This allows you to separate the real model objects from the database accessing methods.

Answer (score 0):

I use the MVCS pattern (Model-View-Controller-Store), which I discovered in Aaron Hillegass's book "IOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" (http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_rd_edition_)

The store is specifically designed to fetch the data, whether it comes from a server, a local file, a persisted collection, a database, etc.

It allows to build very evolutive applications. For example, you can build your application based on a web service, and the day you want to persist your data, you juste have to modify the store, without having to modify a single line of code in your controller.

It's a lot like the Repository Pattern (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) (cf BobTurbo's answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally make a DAO, or data helper class.  It's very hard to follow the strict MVC in objective C when things get more complicated. However, putting it in the model or the VC is not wrong as well.